# Is using os.path.abspath to validate an untrusted filename's location secure?

Tags: python, security

I don't think I'm missing anything.  Then again I'm kind of a newbie.

```
def GET(self, filename):
    name = urllib.unquote(filename)
    full = path.abspath(path.join(STATIC_PATH, filename))
    #Make sure request is not tricksy and tries to get out of
    #the directory, e.g. filename = "../.ssh/id_rsa". GET OUTTA HERE
    assert full[:len(STATIC_PATH)] == STATIC_PATH, "bad path"
    return open(full).read()
```

Edit:
I realize this will return the wrong HTTP error code if the file doesn't exist (at least under web.py).  I will fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.path.abspath`, per se, is quite secure.  Your `assert` check will be compiled away if run under `python -O`, which is one risk.  If your `STATIC_PATH` does not end with the proper directory separator, you might accidentally allow a path which just happens to have it as a prefix -- e.g., if `STATIC_PATH` is `/foo/bar`, you'd erroneously accept a file living under `/foo/barbie/` (so, unless `STATIC_PATH` **does** end with the separator character, you need a slightly stricter check for strong assurance).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about `python -O` but that does make sense.  I suppose because of that I should not use assert in the future just in case I forget its use and end up running `python -O`

I also didn't know `path.join` took that sort of liberty but that's definitely good to know.

Comment: @mcmt, not sure what you mean by `os.path.join` "taking a liberty" -- it _supposed_ to ignore trailing `os.sep` characters in all but the last item, so the path's constructed and `abspath`ed correctly, so you need to check the first `len(staticpath.rstrip(os.sep))+1` of the result vs `staticpath.rstrip(os.sep)+os.sep` unless you otherwise guarantee that the `staticpath` _does_ end with `os.sep`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you were saying.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, dealing with these kinds of issues is a huge pain.  There's always some tricky way of combining path names to create something a programmer didn't expect or plan for.

A better solution is usually to make sure that your webserver is running under a user that *only* has access to the files it needs to have access to.  I think a simple solution to the ssh issue is not to allow this user SSH access.  If you really need to log in under this user, I'd consider logging in under a different account and `su`-ing to it.

Comment: I agree; I just used ssh as an example.  At any rate, when I deploy I'm going to let nginx serve static files.  I was curious as to the issue in general.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that either `STATIC_PATH` ends with a directory separator, or that the character following it in `full` is such.